# How to get geocode latitude and longitude from json google map api in variables by javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

JSON GEO LOCATION
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=KOLKATA&key=API_KEY

```
{
       "results" : [
          {
             "address_components" : [
                {
                   "long_name" : "Kolkata",
                   "short_name" : "Kolkata",
                   "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Kolkata",
                   "short_name" : "Kolkata",
                   "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "West Bengal",
                   "short_name" : "WB",
                   "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "India",
                   "short_name" : "IN",
                   "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
                }
             ],
             "formatted_address" : "Kolkata, West Bengal, India",
             "geometry" : {
                "bounds" : {
                   "northeast" : {
                      "lat" : 23.0078201,
                      "lng" : 88.5428696
                   },
                   "southwest" : {
                      "lat" : 22.3436288,
                      "lng" : 88.19430439999999
                   }
                },
                "location" : {
                   "lat" : 22.572646,
                   "lng" : 88.36389500000001
                },
                "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
                "viewport" : {
                   "northeast" : {
                      "lat" : 23.0078201,
                      "lng" : 88.5428696
                   },
                   "southwest" : {
                      "lat" : 22.3436288,
                      "lng" : 88.19430439999999
                   }
                }
             },
             "place_id" : "ChIJZ_YISduC-DkRvCxsj-Yw40M",
             "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
          }
       ],
       "status" : "OK"
    }
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $("#home_city_select").change(function() {
        //alert( $('option:selected', this).text() );
        var city = document.getElementById("home_city_select").value;
        var ltd;
        var lng;

        var jsonLtdLng="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+city+"&key=API_KEY";
        //alert(JSON.stringify(jsonLtdLng));
        //alert($.getJSON(jsonLtdLng));
        //alert($.getJSON(jsonLtdLng.lat));
        //alert($.getJSON(jsonLtdLng.results.geometry.location.lat));
        //alert($.getJSON(jsonLtdLng.results[0].geometry.location.lat));
        //alert($.getJSON(jsonLtdLng.results[0].geometry.location.lat()));
        alert(jsonLtdLng.results[0].geometry.location.lat());
    });
});
```

Testing in IBM Worklight.

But I cannot get the latitude and longitude

alert(JSON.stringify(jsonLtdLng));//returns full address

alert($.getJSON(jsonLtdLng));//returns object Object

alert($.getJSON(jsonLtdLng.lat));//returns nothing

alert($.getJSON(jsonLtdLng.results.geometry.location.lat));//returns nothing

alert($.getJSON(jsonLtdLng.results[0].geometry.location.lat));//returns nothing

alert($.getJSON(jsonLtdLng.results[0].geometry.location.lat()));//returns nothing

alert(jsonLtdLng.results[0].geometry.location.lat());//returns nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call to [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) was not totally correct

Try this :

```
$.getJSON(jsonLtdLng, function (data) {
  console.log(data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
});
```

Comment: Thanks its working.Tested by alert instead of console.log() but I think there will be a ; semicolon at the end of the statement. console.log(data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);

Comment: What to do if it is in xml format?https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=KOLKATA%20&key=API_KEY,What is the code?

Comment: Json is much easier to parse in javascript than XML, change in the url `xml` with `json`and you will get json again

Comment: just for the knowledge just asking

Comment: and how to get the length of the json?for the loop

Comment: You can use `data.results.length`

Comment: another same code is not working.link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314150/why-this-javascript-is-not-returning-the-restaurant-name

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `console.log()`, `alert()` or `document.write()` as long as the information is deserialized, I am using `JSON.parse()` for deserializing, `eval()` is what people used before. **Deserializing** means to recover the data encoded in json so Javascript can use it as an object. In fact, if you use write.document(someJson) you will see [object object] meaning you have all your data there ready to be used, but you need to `JSON.parse()` it first.   `JSON.stringnify()`  is the opposite of what you want to do, because that function is for **serialize** the data and then transmit it, then the receptor needs to use `JSON.parse()` to deserialized it and use it in Javascript.
I like to use `write.document()` in order to see the information,  but console log allows you to see what is inside of the object easier. Here, some code example:

```
// apiData would be the variable with the API information
var externalData = JSON.parse(apiData);

// will output [object object]     
document.write(externalData);

// will output  “     “
document.write('      ');

// will output the latitude
document.write(externalData.results[0].geometry.location.lat);

// will output in the console, you need to type externalData in the console log 
console.log(externalData);
```

I hope this helps.