# Why this javascript is not returning the restaurant name?

Tags: javascript, json

Address query

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restaurant+in+kolkata&key=API_KEY
```

RESTAURANT JSON LIST

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [
      "Listings by \u003ca href=\"http://www.indiacom.com/\"\u003eIndiacom Yellow Pages\u003c/a\u003e"
   ],
   "next_page_token" : "CuQB2wAAALbNaxylA2QNB4pNRsjUxIOYwTSnii1OIwvXqiCPM3736kQZGJ4sEKthpVgvUkskg0ebaLbeE1iNbNKnO7N__X_FpsGprU3o4scQ5aZuUcroSkZVhuWOKvxWHA9IYVXhFmqrVsgG9mjinq-RvANuV6oKzcvnXK09GvdZR0Xp-HINbfoakOVR0TsoOFNCw4UIWrihFSXPJOXeNtTYuImUrPkYKZVt-Y8xMKxr_aOvRR7L0PfcAcXPpSBB2IugIh2K3ESUGMypJD8EuPW1rqqvvYXcMqqHp8iWzq9h1-ytSFl8EhDn2tzr7gU7AkcPORFyLXuiGhSG1bFqUIK2yQb6_fhN-nbym8c17Q",
   "results" : [
      {
         "formatted_address" : "No. 26,Next To Museum,Sudder Street, New Market Area, Jawaharlal Nehru Road, Kolkata, West Bengal 700016, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 22.558687,
               "lng" : 88.350889
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "68f2d647334cdaa6a4063c86347252f5a6ebe4c1",
         "name" : "Zaranj",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ24Jtvqd3AjoRFb_Bd8Il8Cw",
         "rating" : 4.2,
         "reference" : "CmRZAAAA9-XMiEF-hYPFZh9kaOBwXQ6R-60XStrKsOEkThALaaeHHmJv6kvEd2JWCh7F9XU9XwyNaNRj6KZQkgGEvhhD8qTIs2fiH-Cng5kmlbIpuQLzQGFgQ8dgnvmL2U1-Uz3REhBb9bJSg-t8S8GDpGUGqlsSGhQnqUVV75IG_AFtVpeV4Xpg2YeTmA",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ]
      },
```

JS

```
//Get Restaurant list
function getRestaurants()
{
    var search=$("#search").val();
    var prestring="restaurant+in+";

    var jsonRList="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query="+prestring+search+"&key=API_KEY";
    alert(jsonRList);//returning the address correctly
    $.getJSON(jsonRList, function (data1) {
        var Rname=data1.results[0].name;
        alert(Rname);//returning nothing

    });
}
```

Why this javascript is not returning the restaurant name?(testing first one results[0])

What is the wrong in it?

alert(Rname);//returning nothing

Comment: It's returning value for me. Looks like for that particular keyword you're not getting any result

Comment: Are you getting it from an external page? I would assume that you are trying to alert the value before it has been retrieved. That is a general issue with asynchronous javascript, but i haven't worked with google maps.

Comment: make sure that you are retuning the data without any error. Check the console tab and check for any error.

Comment: I am using IBM WORKLIGHT,Is there any way to show value other than alert?testing on browser console.

Comment: @jogesh_pi on IBM WORKLIGHT no console errors

Comment: Can you open the URL in Google Chrome to test the return value ? By me, I got an "ACCESS_DENIED"

Comment: @huggilou tested some other ways.link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339921/cant-get-the-json-value-by-getjson-from-google-map-api

Comment: @huggilou above link is mine another post

Comment: @huggilou for working of the url, you will have to give valid api key if you have an account of google.https://console.developers.google.com/project

Comment: @huggilou https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKyIVFzkR2A

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `console.log()`, `alert()` or `document.write()` as long as the information is deserialized, I am using `JSON.parse()` for deserializing, `eval()` is what people used before. **Deserializing** means to recover the data encoded in json so Javascript can use it as an object. In fact, if you use write.document(someJson) you will see [object object] meaning you have all your data there ready to be used, but you need to `JSON.parse()` it first.   `JSON.stringnify()`  is the opposite of what you want to do, because that function is for **serialize** the data and then transmit it, then the receptor needs to use `JSON.parse()` to deserialized it and use it in Javascript.
I like to use `write.document()` in order to see the information,  but console log allows you to see what is inside of the object easier. Here, some code example:

```
// apiData would be the variable with the API information
var externalData = JSON.parse(apiData);

// will output [object object]     
document.write(externalData);

// will output  “     “
document.write('      ');

// will output the latitude
document.write(externalData.results[0].geometry.location.lat);

// will output in the console, you need to type externalData in the console log 
console.log(externalData);
```

I hope this helps.

Just for clarification I used  this answer to respond a similar question in this other forum  [How to get geocode latitude and longitude from json google map api in variables by javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298260/how-to-get-geocode-latitude-and-longitude-from-json-google-map-api-in-variables/38156240#38156240))