# Can't get the json value by getjson from google map api

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-maps

Can't get the json value by getjson from google map api

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input data-mini="true" data-theme="a" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search for Restaurants" type="search">
<input data-inline="true" id="submit" onclick="getRestaurants()" type="submit" value="Go">
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
    function getRestaurants()
        {
            var search=$("#search").val();
            var prestring="restaurant+in+";

            var jsonRList="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query="+prestring+search+"&key=API_KEY";
            var xmlRList="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query="+prestring+search+"&key=API_KEY";
            alert(jsonRList);//working

            //NOT working
            $.getJSON(jsonRList, function (data) {
                alert(data.results[0].name);//returns nothing
                alert("hello2");//returns nothing
                });

            //working
            var data = '{"name": "abc","age": 30,"address": {"streetAddress": "88 8nd Street","city": "New York"},"phoneNumber": [{"type": "home","number": "111 111-1111"},{"type": "fax","number": "222 222-2222"}]}';
            var json = JSON.parse(data);
            alert(json.phoneNumber[0].number);

            alert("hello3");//working

            //NOT working
            $.ajax({
                  url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=kolkata&key=API_KEY',
                  dataType: 'jsonp',
                  success: function(data){
                     alert(data);//returns nothing
                     alert("ajax");//returns nothing
                  }
                });

            alert("hello4");//working

//Not working
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $("submit").click(function(){

            $.getJSON( jsonRList, function( data ) {
            alert(data);//returns nothing
            alert("hello5");//returns nothing
            });
          });
        });

        }
```

Inside $.getjson or $.ajax not executing anything.

Another approach that is not working

```
$("button").click(function() {
....
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sphakrrokr/r9xbctnr/

Comment: You should use offical Google Place API : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642418/trying-to-use-google-places-api-with-jquerys-getjson-function

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons I could identify for you not getting a response from Places API -

1) You are using data type JSONP instead of JSON while the API will [return results](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search#TextSearchRequests) in JSON format.

2) Even though you wish to use JSONP and not JSON, you did not implement a `callback`  in order to parse results into JSONP.

For normal use case, I would recommend to use `JSON` over `JSONP`.

Check these resources for difference between the two:

- [Relevant question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp)
- [Relevant question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642418/trying-to-use-google-places-api-with-jquerys-getjson-function)
- [Official docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)